# Conversion of the string into the type double is not valid

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need some help with a VB.Net code, I can´t go through
Every time I run it I get the message

> The conversion of the string is not valid for double

Can you help me with that?

```
    Dim num1 As Double = 0
    Dim num2 As Double = 0
    Dim operacion As Decimal
    ' Asignar n valores a las variables declaradas
    num1 = TextBox1.Text
    num2 = TextBox2.Text
    ' Operacion de incremento porcentual
    operacion = num1 + num1 * num2 / 100
    ' Mostrar el resultado de la operacion mediante un MsgBox - Se redondea el resultado
    MsgBox(Math.Round(operacion, 2), MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Incremento Porcentual")
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use [Double.Parse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) or [CDbl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions)

Comment: The code is ok. The problem must be the strings you have in the textboxes, if the text is not a number you'll get that exception

Comment: Turning option strict on will help you reduce those type of errors

Comment: @Pikoh - No the code is not OK.  The OP is trying to assign the values of the Text properties of the text boxes to variables of type `Double`.  Even if the string in the text box is a valid representation of a `Double` it would still need to be converted before being assigned.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway as I already explained, if `Option Strict` is off, the conversion is automatic and that code would work as is

Answer (score 0):

Apparently with Option Strict off you can do this!

Pikoh's comment is probably correct and you aren't passing a String that can be converted to a Double.

```
If Double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, num1) AndAlso Double.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, num2) Then
  operacion = num1 + num1 * num2 / 100
  MsgBox(Math.Round(operacion, 2), MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Incremento Porcentual")
Else
  MsgBox("Please enter valid numbers")
End If
```

Comment: Are you sure that `Dim num As Double = TextBox1.Text` doesn't work?

Comment: Oh the horror of VB and Implicit conversions! I guess it depends if you have Option Strict on or not, spent too long in C#. I will rewrite with a TryParse expample instead.

Comment: Yes, `Option Strict` is a pain :)

Comment: I couldn't work out how to strike through my previous answer, sorry.

Comment: You don't need to strike through, it's better to edit the answer and just put it right. BTW, i don't think you previous answer was wrong, my comment was just to notice that with option strict off, the casting would be automatic :)

Comment: Option Strict is there to keep developers honest and to discourage them from being lazy about type conversions.  Implicit type conversions are the devil and can be insidious to troubleshoot.